# Why do I have to set 'resizemode' to 'user' twice in order for my change to 'stretchfactor' to take effect when using 'turtle'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm automating the "triangle peg game" found at Cracker Barrel with Python 3.6.0, and I'm currently implementing its graphics with 'turtle'. Two of the classes I've created are relevant to this issue: 'Game' (contained in a module in the main package) and 'TurtleGraphics' (contained in a module in the subpackage 'graphics'), whose intended purposes are self-explanatory. When a 'Game' object is called with a 'TurtleGraphics' object as an argument, the two objects are linked to each other, and 'graphics._construct()' is called, which defines a 'Pen' object and sets its 'stretchfactor' using 'pen()'. Here's where the issue arises. Even though I've set 'resizemode' to 'user' in my 'turtle.cfg' file, I have to set 'resizemode' to 'user' again as an argument to 'pen()' in order for the graphics to construct properly when called from the game. Strangely enough, if I run the module containing 'TurtleGraphics' directly and create a graphics object, it works fine. Also, setting 'stretchfactor' using 'shapesize()' instead of 'pen()' works even when I call the graphics from the game object. First, I'll post the code for 'Game.__call__' and 'TurtleGraphics._construct', prefacing each with the module's imports, which may be relevant. I'll also post 'TurtleGraphics.__init__' and 'TurtleGraphics._draw_board'. (Both classes have base classes, but 'BaseGame' doesn't deal with graphics and 'Graphics' is abstract, so they're irrelevant in this case. Also, it's worth mentioning that 'Game' does not have an '__init__' method. All instance attributes are assigned when it is called.) Then I'll explain the research I've done so far into the matter.

Game.__call__:

```
from tripeg.graphics import Graphics
from tripeg.graphics.ascii_ import ASCIIGraphics
from tripeg.graphics.turtle_ import TurtleGraphics

#...

def __call__(self, graphics=None):
    """Starts the game with given graphics, or none, if not given."""
    super().__call__()
    if graphics:
        if not isinstance(graphics, Graphics):
            raise TypeError(f"Argument '{graphics}' is not of type"
                            " 'Graphics'.")
        else:
            self._graphics = graphics
            self._graphics._game = self
            self._graphics._construct()
```

TurtleGraphics._construct:

```
import os
import turtle
from turtle import Screen, RawPen, Pen, Shape, Terminator, _CFG

from tripeg.graphics import Graphics

#...

def __init__(self):
    """Initialize self. See help(type(self)) for accurate signature."""
    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Sylvaenn\\Python3.6.0\\Programs\\tripeg\\graphics")
    turtle.readconfig("turtle.cfg")

#...

def _construct(self):
    """Constructs the graphics for the game."""
    self.window = Screen()
    self.window.setworldcoordinates(0,0,10,10)
    self._draw_board()

#...

def _draw_board(self):
    """Draws the game board."""
    wh_ratio = self.window.canvwidth / self.window.canvheight

    tri_board = Shape("compound")
    tri_board.addcomponent(((0,0),(8,0),(4,8)),(51,25,0),"black")
    self.window.addshape("tri_board", tri_board)

    board = Pen("tri_board")
    board.pen(pendown=False, outline=7, stretchfactor=(60*wh_ratio,60))
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    board.setheading(90)
    board.goto(1,1)
    board.stamp()
```

Now, here's what I've discovered so far:

I created a breakpoint using 'pdb' and put it directly after 'pen()' is called. When I run the game module and call the graphics from the game, like so...

```
>>> ga = Game()
>>> gr = TurtleGraphics()
>>> ga(gr)
> c:\users\sylvaenn\python3.6.0\programs\tripeg\graphics\turtle_.py(82)._draw_board()
-> board.setheading(90)
(Pdb) !board.pen()
{'shown': True, 'pendown': False, 'pencolor': 'black', 'fillcolor':   'black', 'pensize': 1, 'speed': 3, 'resizemode': 'noresize', 'stretchfactor': (71.46496815286623, 60), 'shearfactor': 0.0, 'outline': 7, 'tilt': 0.0}
(Pdb)
```

...'stretchfactor' has changed, but 'resizemode' is still set to 'noresize' despite the cfg file.

If I run the graphics module and call the graphics directly, like so...

```
>>> gr = TurtleGraphics()
>>> gr._construct()
> c:\users\sylvaenn\python3.6.0\programs\tripeg\graphics\turtle_.py(82)_draw_board()
-> board.setheading(90)
(Pdb) !board.pen
{'shown': False, 'pendown': False, 'pencolor': 'black', 'fillcolor': 'black', 'pensize': 1, 'speed': 3, 'resizemode': 'user', 'stretchfactor': (71.46496815286623, 60), 'shearfactor': 0.0, 'outline': 7, 'tilt': 0.0}
(Pdb)
```

...both 'stretchfactor' and 'resizemode' have the intended values.

What I've Already Tried:

1. analyzed the source code for 'turtle', specifically for 'pen()', '_CFG', and the classes 'Turtle', 'RawTurtle', and their base classes
2. extensively read the tutorial at python.org and method docstrings
3. ran through the program step by step using both the IDLE debugger and 'pdb'

As I said in the beginning, I can make this work by just including "resizemode='user'" in 'pen()' as well as the cfg file, or by using 'shapesize()'. It's just that I want to know why my cfg file isn't serving its intended purpose in all cases, I want to better understand the 'turtle' module and Python in general, and that if I don't understand why this happened, I'm sure I'll run into more serious errors down the road, and I won't be able to fix them.

Comment: Yes, I know this post is rather long, but I'd rather be precise and verbose than vague and concise.

Comment: Precise doesn't necessarily imply verbose. You've put a lot of effort into this, and I thank you greatly for doing so. This sets you apart from a large number of users who barely try. However, in a post this long, there is almost certainly a lot that you could either 1) cut out or 2) isolate in a "background" section that isn't required to understand the question. Believe me, I understand. It's not uncommon for a good question to have a lot of draft text never make it into the post. I think this post would do better if you provided *less* context and focused more on the problem.

Comment: Asking good questions is actually *really* hard, and it's a skill that has to be practiced and mastered. I can tell you have the drive to do so; all you have to do is keep trying. =) Please leave me a comment to ping me after you've trimmed down this question; I'd like to come back and see it.

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback. Regarding programming, I had the "don't leave anything out that could possibly be relevant" mentality drilled into my head somehow. I tend to be rather pedantic in my documentation too, which is certainly better than the opposite, but is something I can definitely improve on. And I will definitely ping you once I trim this down.

Comment: It's not a completely bad thing to have drilled into you. It's much better to start off with too much in the draft phase and then trim it down. You actually need to strike a balance in the final post: you want to include enough info without including too much for readers to process, and unfortunately, it's sometimes even hard to know exactly what info is needed (because knowing what info is needed requires knowing the possible solutions). You'll get better at doing that, and usually, when you're not quite sure what is needed, someone who has an idea of the answer can ask clarifying questions.

Comment: It turns out I don't need to trim down the question, because I got it to work. I posted a response to my question explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know why my cfg file isn't serving its intended purpose in
>   all cases

Here's my analysis of your situation.  The key bit of your code is this:

```
import turtle
#...
def __init__(self):
    os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Sylvaenn\\Python3.6.0\\Programs\\tripeg\\graphics")
    turtle.readconfig("turtle.cfg")
```

Two things to note that might not be obvious:

1. The argument to `turtle.readconfig()` is ignored.  Instead it looks
   for the hardcoded file name "turtle.cfg" in the directory from where
   the *.py source file came from and the current working directory. In
   that order.  Loading both with the second taking priority if both
   exist.  (There's a third possible configuration file I won't go
   into here.)
2. If the `os.chdir()` comes after the `import turtle`, it won't look
   for the configuration file in the directory you just changed into.
   The `os.chdir()` has to come before the `import turtle` if you want
   it to look in the chdir'd directory.  Even with an explicit call to
   `turtle.readconfig()`

To demonstrate this second point, first create a config file in a temporary directory:

```
mkdir temporary_directory
echo "resizemode = user" > temporary_directory/turtle.cfg
```

Run this code:

```
import os
import turtle

from os.path import isfile

current_directory = os.getcwd()

os.chdir("temporary_directory")

turtle.readconfig(None)

print(turtle.resizemode())
```

You'll get the default `noresize` mode.  Run the code again with this modification:

```
import os

from os.path import isfile

current_directory = os.getcwd()

os.chdir("temporary_directory")

import turtle

turtle.readconfig(None)

print(turtle.resizemode())
```

You'll get mode `user`.

Finally, as noted in the turtle documentation, `resizemode('user')` is called by `shapesize()` when `shapesize()` is called with arguments.

Comment: The results I'm getting don't correspond with your answer, though from my reading of the documentation, I thought they would. I tried out your test code, and I actually got "noresize" both times. And I ran through `__init__` in `pdb` and `_CFG` was updated with my cfg file. I actually got my code to work a few hours after I posted this. I'm going to explain it in a post when I finish writing this. Still, thanks for the feedback. At the very least, I learned I can change the argument for `readconfig()` to `None` and it works the same.

Comment: @IsaacSaffold, since I'm using Unix and you're using Windows, and the `os` module is involved, I guess it doesn't surprise me too much that your results differ.  I'm glad you've got things working but I understand your frustration.

Comment: It screwed up again in the same way (I still have no idea how I fixed it temporarily) and I just put `os.chdir` above `import turtle` and it worked. So yours is the solution after all. I appreciate it.